# PayPal REST API - State doesn't change after purchase

Tags: paypal

So I have noticed that when checking on the status of a payment

```
GET /v1/payments/payment/<Payment-Id>
```

the **"state"** of a PayPal response does not change from **"created"** even after the PayPal user has purchased the item. It isn't until I execute the payment that the state changes to **"approved"**.

This makes it difficult to tell the difference between a payment that has actually been approved by a client and one that is still in process as they are both in the **"created"** state. The only difference in the json response is that it seems to include **shipping_address** once the payment has actually been approved. I'm not sure that is a standard way to denote the difference though.

*What is the standard way to tell if a client has actually approved a PayPal transaction when using the above call to the REST API?*

Note: I already have the PHP callback scripts setup and working. I am working on a fail safe system that constantly checks database entries to make sure an approved payment was executed (in case of some system failure).

I thought I could use the IPN callback script I have setup from `CLASSIC API` but it seems that the `REST API` and `CLASSIC API` are not compatible since the IPN callback will not contain a transaction id or any necessary information to be useful.

It seems like when using the REST API, if you miss the redirect call to your webserver then that transaction is lost forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct that you won't tell an approved payment from the `state` field in the lookup API response, instead, you would look for the `payer` object in the JSON body, and that piece of info will indicate an approved payment resource for you.

Here're the JSON responses of the same PAY-ID before/after the customer redirection (user approval)

1. Lookup payment `/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9J02491382988403BK3BMC6I` (before user approval):

   ```
   {
      "id": "PAY-9J02491382988403BK3BMC6I",
      "intent": "sale",
      "state": "created",
      "cart": "07U14103P0008801U",
      "transactions": [   {
         "amount":       {
            "total": "80.00",
            "currency": "USD"
         },
         "payee": {"email": "USM@email.com"},
         "invoice_number": "55a460ff696br",
         "item_list":       {
            "items":          [
                           {
                  "name": "Test Ticket 1",
                  "sku": "55a460ff65f13",
                  "price": "10.00",
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "quantity": 1
               },
                           {
                  "name": "Test Ticket 2",
                  "sku": "55a460ff66c7a",
                  "price": "20.00",
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "quantity": 2
               },
                           {
                  "name": "Test Ticket 3",
                  "sku": "55a460ff66ce2",
                  "price": "10.00",
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "quantity": 3
               }
            ],
            "shipping_address":          {
               "recipient_name": "Test Name",
               "line1": "Main St 1",
               "city": "San Jose",
               "state": "CA",
               "postal_code": "95131",
               "country_code": "US"
            }
         },
         "related_resources": [],
         "notify_url": "https://bt-pduan-1.c9.io/ipn.php"
      }],
      "redirect_urls":    {
         "return_url": "http://localhost:80/getpaypal?paymentId=PAY-9J02491382988403BK3BMC6I",
         "cancel_url": "http://localhost:80/cancel"
      },
      "create_time": "2016-02-16T06:28:08Z",
      "update_time": "2016-02-16T06:28:08Z",
      "links":    [
               {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9J02491382988403BK3BMC6I",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
         },
               {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-9J02491382988403BK3BMC6I/execute",
            "rel": "execute",
            "method": "POST"
         },
               {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-07U14103P0008801U",
            "rel": "approval_url",
            "method": "REDIRECT"
         }
      ]
   }
   ```
2. Lookup the payment after user approval (I'm removing some JSON contents e.g. transaction/url arrays for readablity):

   ```
   {
      "id": "PAY-9J02491382988403BK3BMC6I",
      "intent": "sale",
      "state": "created",
      "cart": "07U14103P0008801U",
      "payer":    {
         "payment_method": "paypal",
         "status": "VERIFIED",
         "payer_info":       {
            "email": "USP@email.com",
            "first_name": "Payer",
            "last_name": "US",
            "payer_id": "8FMFQ2KVYYHTY",
            "shipping_address":          {
               "recipient_name": "Test Name",
               "line1": "Main St 1",
               "city": "San Jose",
               "state": "CA",
               "postal_code": "95131",
               "country_code": "US"
            },
            "phone": "408-743-9795",
            "country_code": "US",
            "billing_address":          {
               "line1": "1 Main St",
               "line2": "",
               "city": "San Jose",
               "state": "CA",
               "postal_code": "95131",
               "country_code": "US"
            }
         }
      },
      "transactions": [],
      "redirect_urls": {},
      "create_time": "2016-02-16T06:28:08Z",
      "update_time": "2016-02-16T06:28:08Z",
      "links": []
   }
   ```

By checking the recorded PAY-ID looking for `payer` object in the API response, your will be able to save the orders and proceed the execute call in case it was missed in the customer return redirection.

Additionaly, neither IPN or webhooks would help in this case as they are async meesages triggered by transactional level events, which means there will be no notification until a payment is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's great to finally get a little help. In my testing with these methods I notice that a "payer" object exists if the user is logged in to paypal but still has not yet paid. In this case it will not have shipping_address however. Once the user has finished checkout and paid it will include shipping_address. Is this the case for you as well?

Comment: I can verify that the "payer" object will exist if the user is sitting on the "review information" page of the store while logged in. At this point they have not yet fully checked out and have the option to cancel still. So the existence of a "payer" object is not enough. I can show you the JSON I get back if that would help.

Comment: This is the payer object while logged in.          "payer": {
    "payer_info": {
      "country_code": "US",
      "first_name": "Joshua",
      "last_name": "Brittain",
      "payer_id": "KZNRYBNVQD2FL",
      "phone": "4084500470"
    },
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "status": "VERIFIED"
  },

Comment: The payer object after checkout includes a billing_address and shipping_address. Perhaps this is enough to denote a successful checkout but I can find no PayPal documentation that this is how it should be done. Your suggestion of only using the "payer" object would fail if the client was logged into PayPal at the time of the request.

Comment: Exactly correct observations, though you won't necessarily have to do the "polling" for payment lookup, but only in your return page as a fall-over for the execute call.

Comment: This won't save the order anyway when there's a customer intended drop off, but still worthwhile for checking the execute API call, giving a second chance for completing the order under particular circumanstances e.g. funding source issue of the customer's card/bank (in which an ERROR 10486 is returned)...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will setup my code to check for state:created and billing_address/shipping_address info in the payer object. I just hope PayPal doesn't decide to change these JSON objects randomly!